# Data endlessly looping after transition to functional components -- Error: Minified React error #185

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im in the process of converting my old class components to functional with react hooks. Doing so, when rendering my header component, it's throwing a `Minified React error #185` error. Console logging the output shows that it is continuously looping over the data which each being logged to the console multiple times.

Previously when this was done with class style components there were no issues. Im not sure what I am overlooking.

**MainLayout Component**

```
const MainLayout = () => {
    const [payload, setPayload] = useState({});
    const [isInit, setisInit] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        payloadApi().then((res) => {
            setPayload(res.data);
            setisInit(true);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('err payload')
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            {isInit && (
                <Header 
                   payload={payload}
                   activeUser="bob"
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

**Header Component**

```
const Header = ({payload, activeUser}) => {
    const renderUserList = () => {
        const filteredUsers = payload.users.filter(function (e) {
            return e.user !== activeUser;
        });

        return filteredUsers.map((k, i) => {
            console.log(k.user);
            return (
                <li key={k.user}>
                    <span>{k.user}</span>
                </li>
            )
        });
    };

    return (
        <header>
           <ul>
             {renderUserList()}
           </ul
        </header>
    );
};
```

**Payload**

```
{
    users: [
      {
          user: "joe",
      }, 
      {
          user: "bob",
      }, 
      {
          user: "sally",
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can spot that might be responsible is the two `set` calls (payload and init), which you don't need anyway. Initialise payload with `null`, and as long it's `null` don't render the `Header`:

```
const MainLayout = ({RouteComponent}) => {
    const [payload, setPayload] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        payloadApi().then((res) => {
            setPayload(res.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('err payload')
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            {payload && (
                <Header 
                   payload={payload}
                   activeUser="bob"
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

You can also prevent needless calls to `renderUserList` with `useMemo`:

```
const Header = ({payload, activeUser}) => {
    const userList = useMemo(() => {
        const filteredUsers = payload.users.filter(function (e) {
            return e.user !== activeUser;
        });

        return filteredUsers.map((k, i) => {
            console.log(k.user);
            return (
                <li key={k.user}>
                    <span>{k.user}</span>
                </li>
            )
        });
    }, [payload, activeUser]);

    return (
        <header>
           <ul>
              {userList}
           </ul>
        </header>
    );
};
```

Comment: Its still endlessly looping than erroring out. Thanks for the input tho.

Comment: Nothing else I can think about. Try to disable every change you make to the state, and if this stops the problem, enable them one by one.

Comment: I've tried that. State shouldn't refresh everything tho right?

Comment: State change should cause a rerender.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. How would one go about managing multiple states then in a component that needs it. Or would breaking everything down smaller solve that

Comment: The main thing is not to cause automatic changes in state after each rerender. However, the components in the question don't do that.

Comment: That perplexes me some because eventually I want to add a button to show / hide this that would be controlled by state.

Comment: That's fine - that's the reason for having state. However, if after render, another something would trigger a state change, that would trigger, and render, state change, etc... The loop is what you should look for.

Comment: what do you mean by that. Wouldn't the blur on the button retrigger state change?

Comment: One event that triggers a state change is what state is for. However, if a state change is trigger, and after the render something causes another state change (in componentDidUpdate in class component or useEffect in functional ones), ... and the loop goes on.